# ASP.NET 4 application issue on iis 6 on windows xp 64bit

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, cross-browser

I have deployed an ASP.NET 4 application to IIS 6 on Windows XP 64bit. This application is working perfectly from an IE8 session launched from Visual Studio 2010 and Cassini from the same XP workstation.

However once I deploy it to IIS 6, on the same box, and open it from IE8 directly, I get all sorts of issues with control widths and layout and also some jQuery errors for my datatable control.

Now here's the really weird part if I open the same IIS 6 web site from firefox using the exact same url everything works fine.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: This seems to be an IE compatibility issue.. Can you check the css path etc using the IE Developer toolbar and confirm that they are correct when opened from IE8??

Comment: Yes right on. So I found some threads that showed how to force ie8 standards mode and now my layout issues have gone away. However there must be something missing as I'm still getting the jquery datatable error, but again only on the iis 6 site, not from within visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have to add a custom header and make sure that you are forcing the ie mode to be 8.
X-UA-Compatible:IE=8